# Can I play GTA 5 with only the first disc?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

So my cousin has GTA V for the 360, and I want it, so he gave me the first disc only. But it keeps telling me to insert Disc 2. Is there a way for me to play GTA V with only Disc 1?

Comment: Games don't usually ship with multiple discs for no reason, you know?

Answer (score 4):

No. You need to install the content from disc two to play the game.

Comment: And have Disc 1 in the drive - i.e. you need both so start saving!

Comment: You mean "yes".

Comment: @AdamJensen I said what I meant.